# Неубиваемый Service (Android)

Tags: android, service

Нужно сделать чтобы мой `Service` не убивался системой и чистилками мусора.

Выполняю такой код:

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Hello");
        Notification notification;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
            notification = builder.getNotification();
        else
            notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(777, notification);
        startService();
    }
```

Вроде бы и картинка, и метка появляются в верхнем меню, но при запуске чистилки `Service` умирает, и не включается, пока его не запустишь вручную.

Comment: "чистилками мусора" GC ща всплакнул

Comment: @katso, думаю речь идет не о GC, а программах, которые псевдо-чистят-оперативку-от-мусора

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно, чтобы сервис не убивался при запуске из него Notification используйте метод startForeground()

Comment: честно не понял, я вроде бы его и использую, может не в том месте использую??? подскажите где

Comment: судя по написанным методам вы вызываете  startForeground() в activity, а это нужно сделать в самом сервисе.

Comment: нет этот код сервиса, при его создании

Comment: убедитесь, что перед тем как вы пользуетесь "чистилками", не вызывается метод stopForeground(). И, главное, может дело в том что у вас не заложено никакой логики в Notification?

Comment: а можете пример такого не убиваемого сервиса дать, а то гугл только тот код показывает, но он у меня почему то не работает(((

Comment: если бы я мог посмотреть на код, то я бы вам лучше помог, чем давать одно за одним предположения основываясь на методе onCreate

Comment: и что это за метод - startService();

Comment: это просто метод в котором происходит чтение данных из SQL и код работы сервиса

Comment: код не помещается сюда, место мало

Comment: если правка для для вас ещё актуальна вот моя почта - sklep4a@gmail.com, сбрасывайте сюда архив разберёмся